# Trying to solve o.d.e., but not sure of integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'd appreciate any help with the attempt at solving an o.d.e.[image]

Comment: Yes, that looks good. What is the actual question? Note that also $I(C(t))=\frac{C_{50}}{C(t)+C_{50}}$.

Comment: The actual question is probably more interesting: I have an indirect response model (first ode above) in which the C(t) are restricted to have the same integral over a given interval (say, 0 to 1). I'm trying to find the C(t) that maximizes the integral of R(t) over this interval. I'm using calculus of variations, but my Euler-Lagrange equation has no solution.

Comment: Did you also try to apply the Pontryagin maximum principle on the ODE directly, without using the solution formula?

Comment: I didn't. I'm not familiar with P.M.P., but, from a quick look, I think that I can make an attempt at it. Thanks!

Comment: On reflection, I'm not sure how to apply PMP to the ode above, because it isn't linear in C and I'm not sure how the constraint that the integral of C=AUC (a fixed constant) can even be included. Any hints?

Comment: Can anyone suggest how I begin applying Pontryagin maximum principle on the ODE directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a Lagrange functional with the point-wise Lagrange multiplier function $ψ(t)$ for the differential equation and 
$$
L(R,C,\psi,\lambda)=\int_0^T\Bigl(R(t)+\psi(t)[R'(t)-k_{in}+k_{out}R(t)I(C(t))]\Bigr)\,dt+λ\left(C_{total}-\int_0^TC(t)\,dt\right)
$$
Variation then gives the additional equations
\begin{align}
\delta R&:~~& ψ'(t)&=1+k_{out}ψ(t)I(C(t)),& ~~ ψ(T)&=0,
\\
\delta C&:~~& 0&=k_{out}ψ(t)R(t) I'(C(t))-λ
\end{align}
which (contrary to the previous erroneous version) is not easily solveable by hand. In numerical terms, this is an ordinary boundary value problem with parameter $λ$ for the system with 3 components $(R,ψ,D)$ where $D'=C$ and $R(0)=R_0$, $D(0)=0$, $ψ(T)=0$ and $D(T)=C_{total}$. In python-scipy `solve_bvp` there is provision for such parameters, in Matlab's `bvpc` afaik not, so that you have to add $λ$ as forth component to the ODE with derivative $0$.

Comment: Thanks! If my understanding is correct, this now becomes a problem with two dependent variables: 
L(t, C, C’, R, R’). Btw, I think that you missed the “R” in “kout*R*I(C).”
So, this becomes
∂L/∂R=  (d )/dt  ∂L/∂R
∂L/∂C=  (d )/dt  ∂L/∂C'

So, using your multipliers, 
1 + ψ*kout*I(C)= ψ’ and 
λ = - ψ*kout*R*C50/(C+ C50)2
The first equation can be solved and obtain a solution similar to my R(t) in the original question. I can’t seem to see how the second equation can be used to utilize the integral condition for C(t), since it appears as a square here.

Comment: The arguments $R,C$ of $L$ are the functions as objects, their derivatives are obtained via linear operators on the functions, they are not extra arguments (like it would be required if the values at one point were the arguments). And yes, you are right.

Comment: Essentially, two equations in 4 unknowns (ψ, C, R and λ). I'm wondering if I add more restrictions (like the integral of C is Ctotal), then this may be more easily solvable. Also, why ψ()=0 ?

Comment: $ψ()=0$ comes from the partial integration for $ψ\delta R'=(ψ\delta R)'-ψ'\delta R$, $\delta R(0)=0$ due to the initial condition fixing the value, $\delta R(T)$ is variable, so the second factor has to be zero. // You also need to count the original DE for $R$ and the integral condition for $C$.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain a little more, such as the terminology ψ?

Comment: This is from computing the variations, that is the first order perturbations when replacing $R$ with $r+δR$ etc. Then transform $δR'$ to $δR$ via partial integration and set the coefficients of these perturbations to zero to get the equations for a stationary point.

Comment: Ok, but if ψ(T)=0 , then 0 = koutψ(t)R(t)I′(C(t))−λ means λ=0.

Comment: Is it a problem that λ=0?

Comment: This then just means that one of $ψ(t)$ and $R(t)$ has to be zero for each $t$, and which one it is can change (when both are zero, which does not happen too often).

Comment: You mention that one can solve these differential equations using Python. This would not be an explicit solution, right, but an approximation.  My gut feeling is that, since the integral of I is minimized at C(t)=Ctotal/T (so, a constant; I think I have the proof from the first and second variations), this would also minimize the integral of R...

Comment: This is directly from integrating differential equation.

Comment: One last comment. I claim that I’(C(t))=0 for all t; that is; C’(t)=0 for all t. Suppose not, and that there is a t* for which  C(t*) ≠ 0. Then, from ∂C equation, since R(t) > 0 for all t (I forgot to mention this), φ(t*) = 0. However, if you solve ∂R for φ, which is a separable differential equation, you get something similar to the solution for R(t) in my original question, namely, an integral of an exponential divided by an exponential. In particular, this can’t be 0.

Comment: I forgot to add: How can I show that this constant function C(t)=AUC/T is a global maximum for the integral of R? Any suggestions?